# Handle React translations on component level

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

What i want to achieve is that i have translations available for all components itself. When i install those components they should render on its own. Another thing that i want to achieve is that my project can overrule translations on component level. This in case if somebody decides that the translations that is in there is not what we want.

What i did in my components is loading `i18n`:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import Cache from 'i18next-localstorage-cache';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(Cache)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: '../dist/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    react: {
      wait: true
    },
    ns: ['authentication'],
    defaultNS: 'authentication',
    debug: false,
    cache: {
      enabled: true
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
      formatSeparator: ',',
      format: function(value, format) {
        if (format === 'uppercase') return value.toUpperCase();
        return value;
      }
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

This is working fine in my storybook but when i load this in my main project, it is using `../` from my build root which is actually not the component itself but my main implementation project.

How can i solve it and how can i ensure that i can even extend this?

UPDATE:
Below a list of the current folder structure like asked in below questions:

```
#Component
dist
--.gitkeep
--locales
--commonjs
--es
src
--actions
----index.js
--components
----compname
------index.js
--reducers
----foo.js
--i18n.js
--index.js
test
.babelrc
package.json
Jenkinsfile

#Project
react
--assets
----css
------app.scss
--dist
----.gitkeep
--src
----index.js
----store.js
webpack.config.js
```

Thanks

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be about i18 but rather a general question about structuring your code base. What do you use to bundle your code? How does your current structure look like?

Comment: @Theo.T, i updated the post itself with the folder structure. Im using babel to compile the code of my component. In the project im using webpack to bundle all if it together to get it shippable.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098400/translation-for-each-component-for-react-i18next

Comment: and https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/299

Comment: The other post was not about this @jamuhl, it was about the internal translation. But overall it is now more about how to extend it on implementation level and how to handle that properly. When i translate the component itself and build it, it works fine but at that point you cannot extend any of this when using it